# How to make bot reply to a mention discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and a problem that has come up for me is that the bot won't reply to the user, here is the code

```
    #Code Imports
import discord
import random
from discord import message
from discord import channel
from discord.embeds import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.bot import Bot
from discord.message import Message
from apikeys import *
from discord import guild
from discord import emoji
from discord import *
from discord import ContentFilter
from discord import channel
from discord import client

#intents
intents=discord.Intents.default()
intents.members=True
#prefix
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)
#Start
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for emoji in client.emojis:
        print("Name:", emoji.name + ",", "ID:", emoji.id)
    print('Bot is Online {0.user}'.format(client))
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
client.remove_command('help')
#Commands

@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    await ctx.send('use !war to get up the war menu')

emojigood = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
emojibad="\N{THUMBS DOWN SIGN}"



@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title='Help', description='!war is currently under testing please do not complain about it', color=0x00000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed) 

@client.command()
async def war(ctx): 
    embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='You are starting a war, do you want to continue?', color=0x00000)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojigood)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojibad)
    def check(r, user):
        return (r.emoji == emojigood or r.emoji == emojibad) and r.message == msg
    #Checks whether the message is the same, and the emoji is one of the accepted ones, and returns either True or False
    r, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add',timeout=10 ,check=check)
    #this is equivalent to a event listener within your command, it will stop there until a reaction that meets the requirements has been found 
    #(This won't block other commands and functions)
    if r.emoji == emojigood:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='Please now choose a country', color=0x00000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


prefix = "!" #insert your prefix 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == f'{prefix}war': #dont need to use this string, just illustrating the point
        await message.channel.send("What country do you want to start a war with?")
        def check(msg):
            return msg.author == message.author and len(msg.role_mentions) > 0
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        role = msg.role_mentions[0]
        channel = client.get_channel(849230881994047508)
        await channel.send(f"{role.mention} {message.author} has declared war on you.")

    
    
     


    

  



client.run(token)
```

What's meant to happen:
Bot: Which role would you like to start a war with
User:@something
Bot:Send information to UN, 'War on @something'

I don't know how to make it see the role mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues, the way to make the code you're using function decently is to replace `message.content` with `message.clean_content`, however, 1. That will react to any message starting with @ or a mention, which is probably not what you want, and 2. any message not *beginning* with the mention wouldn't work.

You say in your description that you're looking for role mentions, which is a different attribute, and you're looking to send a message, and wait for a response, so here's a piece of sample code that would solve those issues, assuming I'm interpreting your question correctly:

```py
def check(msg):
    return msg.author == message.author and len(msg.role_mentions) > 0
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
role = msg.role_mentions[0]
channel = client.get_channel(ID of the channel)
await channel.send(f"{role.mention} {message.author} has declared war on you."
```

If I misinterpreted any of what you wanted or you're not sure how some of it works, shoot me a comment and I'll do my best to explain!

Docs reference for slightly more complex objects used:
[role_mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.role_mentions),
[wait_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for),

Comment: I actually don't need the    if message.content == f'{prefix}war start': #dont need to use this string, just illustrating the point
        await message.channel.send("What country do you want to start a war with?


I already have that code in my terminal, so would I need to delete the code in python?

Comment: If you don't have that, itll respond to every single message not sent by itself, which would be massively irritating

Comment: SInce i don't know how to possibly fix that, I send you my code,

Comment: Now it should apply better

Comment: Now I get an error saying await requires async, when I put in async it shows the same error,  removing the return code helps

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what's going on with your code on your end, so heres a paste-bin, it's working for me https://pastebin.com/PKQf3SDi I tested it on a private server, should be good

Comment: Now i get this error Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send', but the error happens when I type in @role

Comment: I also had to remove self, as it said that ctx wasn't there

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PKQf3SDi this worked perfectly when i tested this, really hope it finally works

Comment: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is entirely on your end now, There are *0* sets in the pastebin, if you send back what code you're currently using in your own pastebin, I'll see what i can do

Comment: I tried the code again and it does do invalid role mentioned but nothing else

Comment: What are you using to host your bot?

Answer (score 0):

```
if client.user.mention in message.content :
            await message.channel.send(f"{bot_response}", reference=message)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**